# Reading property file from external path in spark scala throwing error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read property file from external path in spark scala like this :

```
spark-submit --class com.spark.scala.my.class --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn --files /user/mine/dev.properties /path/to/jar/dev-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-uber.jar 2020-08-19T06:00:00Z 2020-08-20T07:00:00Z
```

and I am reading like this:

```
    val props = new Properties()
    val filePath = SparkFiles.get("/user/mine/dev.properties")
    LOGGER.info("Path to file  : "+ filePath)
    val is= Source.fromFile(filePath)
    props.load(is.bufferedReader())
```

I also tried like this:

```
val is= Source.fromFile("/user/mine/dev.properties")
```

But getting file not found exception in both:

```
diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /hadoopfs/fs1/data/hdfs1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1598445422718_5591/spark-78c8ae71-3381-4317-90e1-d5a6da6b2956/userFil9a-b3c7-4b24-8227-441837/user/mine/dev.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
```

and when i dont use spark.file I get this :

```
20/11/17 07:57:45 INFO Client:
         client token: Token { kind: YARN_CLIENT_TOKEN, service:  }
         diagnostics: User class threw exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /user/mine/dev.properties (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
        at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:54)
```

Comment: can you try with : "dev.properties" . instead of  "/user/mine/dev.properties"

Comment: @maximeG Same error

Comment: you have HDFS mounted in that path. I suppose you are running the Spark driver in a container with a HDFS route mapped in your file system. Change the properties file location.

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44. I didnt get your point.
and if i print the path I used in first method it is same as the path thrwoing error>
This sis path printed by logger statement:
```
/hadoopfs/fs1/data/hdfs1/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/user/appcache/application_1598445422718_5591/spark-78c8ae71-3381-4317-90e1-d5a6da6b2956/userFil9a-b3c7-4b24-8227-441837/user/mine/dev.properties
```